# Attendance System with Google Apps Script

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, raspberry-pi, time-and-attendance

I am new to Python and I am wondering if I can use Google Apps Script with Python so that it would automatically send an e-mail to those who have been tardy for a number of times. I am also thinking to make a system out of my Raspberry Pi with QR codes from the students. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm sure there is a way... But you need to do the research by yourself. This is a Q&A for specific programming related question and not a general question dump. Please read [ask].

Comment: Welcome. Python access to Google Scripts is via the API. The [Google Sheets API v4-Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) might be a useful read. On a tangent, you said _automatically send an e-mail to those who have been tardy for a number of times_; this seems to be the jumping off point, and you need to create a definition for "tardy for a number of times" and the mechanism by which it can be measured. Many attendance systems use Google Forms and Sheets-if you do too, then targeting a Google search might yield other relevant topics and answers.